# Remove spacing between table rows in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

Let me start by saying that I haven't built an HTML email in a long time; I've been spoiled by CSS for far too long, so going back to building things with tables is incredibly frustrating. I am having trouble getting two  rows to sit flush against each other; there is a gap that I can't eliminate, no matter what I've tried. Scouring other posts on S.O. only yields solutions I've already tried and that have not worked. About 40% of the intended audience is viewing emails on Outlook, meaning CSS support is incredibly limited. Things I've tried:

- border-collapse:collapse (which I already put in place by default from the start)
- setting margin: 0 (just about everywhere)
- cellspacing and cellpadding to zero (which I already did by default when building the tables).
- display:block and display:inline-block (not really supported by Outlook, but didn't solve my problem anyway).

Here are my code snippets (ignore any CSS classes; again there is not yet any embedded CSS, those are just placeholders at this point. Any embedded CSS will primarily be to handle email client-specific issues.)

```html
<!--2 Column Layout : BEGIN-->
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="stack-column-center" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
                <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/monkey_wrench_zpstk6rgf3j.png" width="300" alt="Monkey Wrench" border="0" class="fluid">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>

        <td class="stack-column-center" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
                <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/auto_parts_zpsf1bs9tgv.png" width="300" alt="Auto Parts" border="0" class="fluid">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<!--2 Column Layout : END-->

<!--2nd Hero Image : BEGIN-->
<tr>
  <td class="full-width-image">
    <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/sliced-bread_zpsxt8z6pjt.png" width="600" alt="Sliced Bread" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">
  </td>
</tr>
<!--Hero Image : END-->
```

*The small gap at the bottom of the row is visible if you look closely. It is 4px in height.*

[image: The small gap at the bottom of the row is visible if you look closely. It is 4px high.]

Comment: please check if image added at bottom has top border with white color or transparent of 4 px ???

Comment: In my experience, this is usually due to inline images.  You can try the inline-block IE trick: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: @DrJManish that was my very first thought; the image is fully cropped

Comment: @circusdei just tried it, but that didn't seem to do the trick. Outlook doesn't support  the "display" property after Outlook 2003 anyway (which is rather bizarre to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `display:block` wasn't a solution, I tried removing the `<!doctype html>` declaration and that fixed the issue. Normally I don't think this would be acceptable, but to the best of my knowledge - and after testing - it does not have any negative impact for **HTML email**.

Answer (score 1):

I t looks good; not bad. Also, you don't need to add all the css details to each row and column; just add:  or  or ; and then in your css sheet (If you don't have it then just create on) add td.Whatever-you-decide-to-name-it or tr.Whatever-you-decide-to-name-it or table.Whatever-you-decide-to-name-it.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I agree that it doesn't look all that bad, but my designer likes to design full flowing layouts in AI and then slice them into images; white space is not preferred because the intent is to have the entire email flow as one cohesive design. The placeholder images I have in there are not really good examples of what the final aesthetic would be. Yeah, I should have cleaned up the CSS before posting - most of that is byproduct of me throwing everything at the wall and seeing if anything would stick. Will def. clean up before production.

Comment: css should be embeded fully in html email itself... because many email client block external links..... just additional input by me...

Comment: Yes you can embed CSS in html with this solution too; what I meant was to do it all underneath, as this will help organise it a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `img` is not containing a width (even `auto`), initialize it as a block element.Since you have mentioned that block is not supported in your case I added `display:table` for your `img`. I added the working snippet with this answer.

```css
img {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!--2 Column Layout : BEGIN-->
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="stack-column-center" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
                <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/monkey_wrench_zpstk6rgf3j.png" width="300" alt="Monkey Wrench" border="0" class="fluid">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>

        <td class="stack-column-center" style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:0px; border-spacing:0px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; padding:0px; border-width:0px; margin:0px;">
                <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/auto_parts_zpsf1bs9tgv.png" width="300" alt="Auto Parts" border="0" class="fluid">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<!--2 Column Layout : END-->

<!--2nd Hero Image : BEGIN-->
<tr>
  <td class="full-width-image">
    <img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y303/aadBresco/sliced-bread_zpsxt8z6pjt.png" width="600" alt="Sliced Bread" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">
  </td>
</tr>
<!--Hero Image : END-->
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, display:block is not supported by most versions of Outlook so it isn't a viable solution for this application. Also, it didn't work in browser when I tried it, so its doubly moot.

Comment: So you can  try `display:table` for `img` It will help you

Comment: The entire "display" property is unsupported after Outlook 2003.